# Wifi - auto homing for best signal strength

Tags: wireless-networking

Is it possible to make devices on wifi automatically switch to the AP with the best signal strength or data quality?

I have a small office that is divided into rooms by brick/concrete walls. If not for the walls, a single AP would have provided excellent coverage, an overkill in fact. But because of the walls, I have to put up additional APs. The problem is that once locked onto an AP, a device won't let go until it is totally out of range. When a person moves from one room to another, his device can persist on a very low quality connection that was originally established when he was in the other room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an amazingly concrete and well written blog about exactly this problem [here](http://wifinigel.blogspot.com/2015/03/what-are-sticky-clients.html?m=1).

I’ll quote the conclusion, but I really recommend reading the entire blog, because it gives great details and explanations.

> Possible approaches to mitigate sticky behaviour, including:
>
> - Giving clients better information through standards based approaches (802.11k & 802.11v)
> - Limiting lower data rates to encourage roaming
> - Using vendor-supplied techniques which rely on actions based on received RSSI signal levels